# I Need Moore(less) Chips

Tags: code-golf

If you wanted to compute a very <strike>large</strike> long problem, that on a machine that you could buy today for an inflation adjusted price, will take some amount of years/decades. The issue is, if you only have that budget, and so can only purchase one machine. So if you purchase the machine now, it may actually take longer to compute than if you purchase one later, for the same [inflation adjusted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_versus_nominal_value_(economics)) price, because of Moore's Law.

[Moore's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%27s_law) states that machines will double in everything every two years, so, theoretically, a problem that takes m years to compute now, will only take m/2 years 2 years from now. The question is, how long should I wait to buy the machine, if I need to compute a problem that takes m years to compute, to get the optimal time of computation, which is inclusive of the time waited to buy the machine, and how much time does it take?

It is assumed both that I gain no money, and make just enough interest on my money to beat inflation, but no more, and also that Moore's Law continues ad infinitum.

some examples:

| years | time-to-wait | time-it-takes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 years | 0 seconds, buy now! | 0 years |
| 1 year | 0 seconds, buy now! | 1 year |
| 2 years | 0 seconds, buy now! | 2 years |
| 3 years | 0.1124 years | 2.998 years |
| 4 years | 0.9425 years | 3.828 years |
| 5 years | 1.5863 years | 4.472 years |
| 7 years | 2.557 years | 5.443 years |
| 8 years | 2.942 years | 5.828 years |
| 10 years | 3.586 years | 6.472 years |
| 20 years | 5.586 years | 8.472 years |
| 100 years | 10.23 years | 13.12 years |
| 1000000 years | 38.81 years | takes 39.70 years |

Code-golf, so shortest answer wins.

Desmos example text:

`f\left(t\right)=N\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2}^{\frac{t}{2}}\right)+t`

Comment: What's the acceptable I/O? Input as integer years, and return two float/doubles, or do you want string parsing and formatted returns as well? Also in your table, the bottom right entry is formatted differently from the rest.

Comment: No formatting necessary, float/double input, and float or double output

Comment: I believe `time-to-wait` of `1000000 years` is off by 2 -> 36.81, not 38.81

Comment: We're supposed to return both `time-to-wait` and `time-it-takes`, right?

Comment: What's the maximum `N` we have to be precise to and to what ±x%?

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES7), 52 bytes

```js
f=eval(`
with(Math)a=>[b=max(0,log2(a*LN2)*2-2),b+a/2**(b/2)]
`)
```

```html
<input oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value)><pre id=o>
```

Edit: Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Samathingamajig.

Comment: Wow. I have an 87 byte solution I've been working on for about 2 hours using Newton's method, but this is clearly better

Comment: Based on the wording of the question, "how long should I wait to buy the machine ... and how much time does it take", you need to return both `time-to-wait` and `time-it-takes`

Comment: You don't need any of those newlines btw

Comment: You actually don't even need eval, just do `with(Math)f=a=>max(0,log2(a/LOG2E)*2-2)`

Comment: @Steffan The byte count is for the second line only. The rest just makes it easier to test.

Comment: @Samathingamajig Sorry, I'm terrible at interpreting questions correctly. I'll update my answer shortly.

Comment: You can use `*LN2` instead of `/LOG2E`, since `(1 / log_a(b)) == log_b(a)`, for -2 bytes

Comment: @Samathingamajig Huh, I had no idea that constant existed, thanks!

Comment: @Neil Even if it didn't, `log` by default is `ln` so you could've saved 1 byte

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>29</s> 28 bytes

```
{y+#/√2^y,y>0}~Minimize~y&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7v7pSW1n/Uccso7hKnUo7g9o638y8zNzMqtS6SrX/AUWZeSXRyrp2fg5pDsqxanXByYl5ddVcBjpchjpcRjpcxjpcJjpcpjpc5jpcFkBBoIQRSNIAQoAAV@1/AA)

Returns `{time-it-takes, {y->time-to-wait}}`.

There's a built-in. All is well.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (GCC)](https://gcc.gnu.org), <s>79</s> 77 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to [@Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil)*

```
f(x,r)double*r,x;{r[1]=(*r=fmaxl(0,2*log(x*log(2)/2)/log(2)))+x/pow(2,*r/2);}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NZBdagMhFIWfM6u4DBTUcRrHtjQg0xW0K7BS0mkNgfkJJqEXhllJX_ISuqNCd1Pv_Ih-Hi-H49Xva_W2q6ofm-Z1k7rL9Xzy-ebvxTOUgX905_f6UwSJpg-2cCUTofTNFmumpBZ1t2M4UvN1nJPiPMP1oftiWooQy2aYQ3-b7b5lvE9WUy7g0ToooVe3SkJB0IQ7wj3hgfBI2IyW0agnu1o2GiTzmDCYJFn5LrD5BoExH4-GxFMJykCWIYfYwtJDsNqZePRMoITASR_Cvj15lt74Z1jWa5tKGC1WOWLhyDsk8-su89f9Aw)

Comment: Do you need the `()`s around `*r/2`?

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
2Æl2÷«ɓ÷l2Ḥ»0,+¥
```

A monadic Link that accepts a positive number, `m` years, and yields a list of two numbers, `[wait, total]` in years.

Note: Input is strictly positive - inputting `0` will yield `[nan, nan]` which is *technically* true as one cannot do anything in zero time.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f9qZWxsef//MsOGbDLDt8KryZPDt2wy4bikwrswLCvCpf///zEwMA)**

#### How?

```
2Æl2÷«ɓ÷l2Ḥ»0,+¥ - Link: number, M
2                - two
 Æl              - natural logarithm
   2÷            - two divided by that
     «           - minimum with M
      ɓ          - start a new dyadic chain - f(M, CalculationTime=that)
       ÷         - M divided by CalculationTime
        l2       - log-base-two
          Ḥ      - halved
           »0    - maximum with zero
               ¥ - last two links as a dyad - f(WaitTime=that, CalculationTime)
              +  -   WaitTime add CalculationTime = TotalTime
             ,   -   WaitTime paired with that -> [WaitTime, TotalTime]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 35 bytes

*- a lot from ATT*

```
2{a=Ramp@Log2[Log@2#/2],a+#/2^a/2}&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b736g60TYoMbfAwSc/3SgaSDgYKesbxeokagOpuER9o1q1/2n6DtWGOkY6xjomOqY6ZjrmOhY6ljqGBkAExiBQq6/vp68fUJSZV/IfAA)

---

Explanation:

`2` Take twice

`{a=Ramp@` zero or

`Log2,` the base-2 logarithm

`Log@2` of the natural logarithm of 2

`#` times the input

`/2]` divided by two.

`, a` Then, output this

`+#/` plus the input divided by

`2^a` two to the power of the variable,

`/2}&` all divided by two.

Comment: [35 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b736g60TYoMbfAwSc/3SgaSDgYKesbxeokagOpuER9o1q1/2n6DtWGOkY6xjomOqY6ZjrmOhY6ljqGBkAExiBQq6/vp68fUJSZV/IfAA). When golfing you don't need to worry about localizing variables (usually), `Ramp` is `Max[0,#]&`, `Log2` exists, use a few logarithm transformation rules, and finally double after everything else so you don't need to parenthesize `(a/2)`.

Comment: Wow. I guess if you put it in a list, the Slots still apply and you can get rid of the Block?

Comment: `Slot`s work anywhere inside a pure function. Also, `#/2^a/2` is \$\left.\frac{\texttt{#}}{2^a}\right/2\$, not \$\frac{\texttt{#}}{2^{a/2}}\$.

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 87 bytes

```js
s=(n,x=3,i=999,l=Math.LN2)=>i?s(n,x+2/l-2**(x/2+2)/n/l/l,i-1):[x=x>0?x:0,n*.5**(x/2)+x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZHfaoMwFMbvfYpz0QttYzQxtlpJ9wLb2L2VVsRubjaOKp0gfXaXY2TCQuDwffmdL/8@83veFrfqu3Pv0Ti20laklwGpZBzHpJYvefdBn1@5Iw/VU4uLG@7VLl@v7d7jG@54yqu9mlQuc/ZpL/uD/9TvfaLWNDSMs@mzMbGKRrUdFHlbtiAhtQBSnwDOjKBgk2BG8ElwIwItKGNcaIfGcWRcgW4seEggoBGfXa0YDaOt7hFU7OaEHXaGoS4hFSIwZjTFCY7mXz/zMU4HENgu/dxHaHKjxWU@HtinXG/GAsoWG4fO2dJI3yqI6Q7vmCWWdWluYJuXSBWBn7zqCHT5V5lBczGP48CgU2bmejLI9WQgCfoLnGQGmrqkdfNun5VcDeqRHDuk97AasD7APRy71WAyaNe83cqiaqtG2cJBGCMRxrrAqP7DZ73lwxp/AQ)

Returns both `time-to-wait` and `time-it-takes`. You could remove 1 byte to make it less precise at higher values, as 86 fits all test cases, but the problem does not tell a range you have to be precise to.

This uses [Newton's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) on the first derivative of the function given to find the minimum.

Pre-golfed code: (derivatives found with [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/))

```js
const f=(x,n)=>n*.5**(x/2)+x; // f(t)
const g=(x,n)=>1-n*2**(-x/2-1)*Math.LN2; // f'(t)
const h=(x,n)=>2**(-2-x/2)*n*Math.LN2**2; // f''(t)

const solution = n => {
  let x = 3; // arbitrary number that seems to work
  for (let i = 0; i < 999; i++) {
    // console.log(x);
    x = x - g(x,n)/h(x,n);
  }
  x = Math.max(0,x);
  return [x, f(x,n)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## x86 64-bit machine code, 30 bytes

```
D9 EA D8 C0 D9 E8 DB 2F DB F2 72 0D D8 F2 D9 F1 D8 C0 D9 C9 D8 C1 DB 3F C3 DE D9 D8 E0 C3
```

This takes in RDI a pointer to a double-extended-precision floating-point number, used both for the input \$m\$ and for the output of total time taken, and returns the waiting time on the FPU register stack.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLbbtswDH2OvoLwkEFKlSJxuwvsZQ8r9rYBQ5GHDWkeZF0cDbJs@NI5DfLr8ygHK7J0BiSR55CHNCVZVfNcymF4Zb10ndLwoWmVLa93H8k/kLPZJVZbnweM6L7VtYfoLoKDK30Oquwyp8HQc2/Ws/RIRFMAhfuIkuvclZlwYIhJJsYpF2syMUIpaFq6YPx0kEAtxx3Wn36sP8O39T1samW3CMqysGfhMYb/zMAho@zjBWH2Lu7/X6GXu2Av2Qt6hJq2elm71i1xydhCVYWgLruQDREsApYSYn0LhbCeBkPUueQgd6KG2QydR0YOZBKYHlaw4LAPR3qCWrnZontAeMkh5nDD4ZbDGw7vOLxHEIk4kIvTFr4j5pqyhrFaAQmKYDtYY3J@HxnKFukFKBA09HXGAlHhDbeGRlObwPSLCevBRxwKDoLDGHMkz1EP/quQO@s1yFLpJAr0@EMphD6e0IwRUiUc/qbAdBF/R8H9itLONzb3Wo2DmTHDNv3V1RafDPzaWeyMPsF8BRRng5L93Q0L@s9CdGoh27e6YWOHfSBx/h0@S5zkkQzDb2mcyJthXry9xQ3f4QpztfsD)

Letting \$x\$ be the running time in years, the total time is \$ 2\log_2(m/x) + x \$. The derivative of that is \$ \frac{2}{\ln(2)} \frac xm \frac{-m}{x^2} + 1 = \frac{-2}{\ln(2)x} + 1 \$, which is zero when \$ x = \frac{2}{\ln(2)} = 2\log_2(e)\$. Therefore, that is the optimal value if it is valid – if \$m\$ is at least that value.

In assembly:

```
f:  fldl2e                  # Push log_2(e) onto the FPU register stack.
    fadd st(0), st(0)       # Double it by adding it to itself.
    fld1                    # Push 1 onto the FPU register stack.
    fld TBYTE PTR [rdi]     # Push m onto the FPU register stack.
    fcomi st(0), st(2)      # Compare m and 2*log_2(e).
    jb low                  # Jump if m < 2*log_2(e).
    fdiv st(0), st(2)       # Divide m by 2*log_2(e).
    fyl2x                   # Taking the top two values (m/(2*log_2(e)), 1) as (x, y),
                            # replace them with y*log_2(x).
    fadd st(0), st(0)       # Double the result, getting the waiting time.
    fxch st(1)              # Exchange values, moving 2*log_2(e) to the top.
    fadd st(0), st(1)       # Add the waiting time to 2*log_2(e) for the total time.
    fstp TBYTE PTR [rdi]    # Store that at the address and pop it off the stack.
    ret                     # Return.
low:
    fcompp                  # Compare the two values on top of the stack and pop both.
    fsub st(0), st(0)       # Subtract the remaining value from itself, producing 0.
    ret                     # Return. (The value at the address is unchanged.)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), 20 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
žr.²/.²·Í¾‚àÐ;oIs/+‚
```

Port of [*@Neil*'s JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247033/52210).

Uses the legacy version of 05AB1E, because apparently `o` (\$2^a\$ builtin) doesn't work for zero as float (`0.0`)..

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//6L4ivUOb9IH40PbDvYf2PWqYdXjB4QnW@Z7F@tpAzv//hgYGAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/o/uK9A5t0gfiQ9sP9x7a96hh1uEFhydY51cW62sDOf91/kcb6BjqGOkY65jomOqY6ZjrWOgYGugYAUUNwBgEYgE).

**Explanation:**

```python
žr                   # Push builtin e
  .²                 # Take the base-2 logarithm of it
    /                # Divide the (implicit) input-integer by this
     .²              # Get the base-2 logarithm of that again
       ·             # Double it
        Í            # Decrease it by 2
         ¾‚          # Pair it with 0
           à         # Get the maximum of this pair
            Ð        # Triplicate this maximum
             ;       # Halve the top copy
              o      # Push 2 to the power this
               Is/   # Push the input, and divide it by this value
                  +  # Add it to the other maximum-copy
                   ‚ # Pair it with the remaining maximum
                     # (after which this pair is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>73</s> 70 bytes

```py
from math import*
lambda a:[b:=log2(max(a*log(2),2))*2-2,b+a/2**(b/2)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYtBDoIwFET3nGKWbf0G/GgkJJyEsGijCAmlTfkLPX0FncVk8l4mfmQKa93ElPOYgoe3MmH2MSQxxdgt1ruHhW1713ZLeLHy9q2s2adiTay14TOTO9mSjVGuZD1keW6yoUNfES4EJtSEK@FGuBOaHe6CD1n968hQjCFBMK/4/dsCiGleRQlhVKJ1/gI)

- -3 Thanks to [att](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81203/att), since [image: 1/(log_a(b)) == log_b(a)]

Comment: You don't need to count the `f=`, and `/log2(e)` -> `*log(2)` for -3.